# How to (spatial) JOIN many tables to each row of another BigQuery table?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, gis, geopandas

**Introduction**

This (fully reproducible) question:

1. Shows how to create mock data
2. Shows how I'd like to data to be processed, using GeoPandas
3. Shows how to upload data to Google BigQuery & start basic processing
4. Asks how to do the same processing of these tables as done with GeoPandas dataframes, this time using BigQuery, especially it's [Geography functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions).

---

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
```

---

### Mock Data Creation

Let's have a few shapely ([docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)) polygons, and `ps`, a list of these polygons:

```
p0 = Polygon([[0,0],[2,0],[2,1],[0,1]])
p1 = Polygon([[1,-1],[1.5,-1],[6.5,1],[5,1]])
p2 = Polygon([[8,-1.5],[10,-1.5],[10,-1],[8,-1]])
ps = [p0,p1,p2]
```

I also have a few list of shapely Points, let's call each list a "track":

```
track0 = [Point(x,y+0.4) for x, y in zip(np.linspace(0,10,30),np.linspace(-0.1,1,30))]    
track1 = [Point(x,np.sin(x)-0.8) for x in np.linspace(0,8,50)]    
track2 = [Point(9,x) for x in np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,8)]
```

A list of these tracks:

```
tracks = [track0,track1,track2]
```

To visualize these objects, we can do:

```
for p in ps:
    x, y = p.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x,y)

for track in tracks:
    for p in track:
        x, y = p.xy
        plt.scatter(x,y,c='r',s=2)
```

[image]

I create a GeoDataFrame from the polygons. Each polygon will have a name as well:

```
polydf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':ps,'name':['a','b','c']})
```

Create GeoDataFrames from each track too:

```
track0df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':track0})
track1df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':track1})
track2df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':track2})
```

A list of these GeoDataFrames:

```
trackdfs = [track0df,track1df,track2df]
```

---

### Processing using GeoPandas

From the dataframe of polygons, and the list of track dataframes, **I aim to create dataframes containing the intersection of each track with each polygon.** 3 polygons, 3 tracks, that's maximum 9 dataframes. If a track and a polygon do not meet, then there is no need for a dataframe. I do:

```
resdf={}
for i, trackdf in enumerate(trackdfs):                    # iterate over each track
    for poly, name in zip(polydf.geometry,polydf.name):   # iterate over each polygon
        filtered = trackdf[trackdf.geometry.within(poly)] # which points from track are within polygon
        if len(filtered) > 0:                             # if more than 0 points are within polygon, then...
            resdf[f'{i}_{name}'] = filtered               # ...add dataframe to the result, a dict of dfs
```

`resdf` will be:

```
{'0_a':                   geometry
 1  POINT (0.34483 0.33793)
 2  POINT (0.68966 0.37586)
 3  POINT (1.03448 0.41379)
 4  POINT (1.37931 0.45172)
 5  POINT (1.72414 0.48966),
 '0_b':                    geometry
 14  POINT (4.82759 0.83103)
 15  POINT (5.17241 0.86897)
 16  POINT (5.51724 0.90690)
 17  POINT (5.86207 0.94483)
 18  POINT (6.20690 0.98276),
 '1_a':                    geometry
 6   POINT (0.97959 0.03027)
 7   POINT (1.14286 0.10982)
 8   POINT (1.30612 0.16518)
 9   POINT (1.46939 0.19486)
 10  POINT (1.63265 0.19809)
 11  POINT (1.79592 0.17477)
 12  POINT (1.95918 0.12552),
 '1_b':                     geometry
 16  POINT (2.61224 -0.29503)
 17  POINT (2.77551 -0.44204)}
```

Notice that each `key` contains the number of the track and the `name` of the polygon which were used to produce the corresponding table value (separated by an `_`).

Check `resdf` dict by plotting the dataframes it contains as values:

```
for p in ps:
    x, y = p.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x,y)

for f in resdf.values():
    x, y = zip(*f.geometry.apply(lambda row: row.xy))
    plt.scatter(x,y,c='r',s=2)
```

[image]

Looks ok.

---

### Upload to BigQuery

Now I upload the dataframes I've worked with to BigQuery. The dataframe with the polygons:

```
polydf.to_wkt().to_gbq('ourdataset.polydf',project_id='ourproject',if_exists='replace')
```

The track dataframes are also uploaded:

```
for i, trackdf in enumerate(trackdfs):
    trackdf.to_wkt().to_gbq(f'ourdataset.track{i}df',project_id='ourproject',if_exists='replace')
```

**Go from `STRING` to `GEOGRAPHY`**

The data was uploaded as strings. Change data type to BQ's `GEOGRAPHY` datatype. Table containing Polygons:

```
%%bigquery
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ourdataset.proc_polydf AS
(
    SELECT SAFE.ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(geometry,make_valid => TRUE) AS geometry, name AS name
    FROM `ourproject.ourdataset.polydf`
)
```

Do the same `STRING` -> `GEOGRAPHY` process for the tables of tracks:

```
for i in range(len(trackdfs)):
    query_text = \
    f'''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ourdataset.proc_track{i}df AS
    (
        SELECT SAFE.ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(geometry,make_valid => TRUE) AS geometry
        FROM `ourproject.ourdataset.track{i}df`
    )
    '''
    query_job = client.query(query_text)
```

I save these new tables to `proc_polydf`, `proc_track0df`, `proc_track1df`, `proc_track2df`. The `proc_` prefix indicates that the columns containing polygons and points are now `GEOGRAPHY` types, not `STRING`s.

---

## Question

I would like to do the same in BigQuery as I did in GeoPandas. Take every table of tracks and get the points from it which are within the polygon of a particular row of the polygons table. I would like to save the result in a new table, with a name including the `name` entry from the column the polygon is taken from, and the name of the track's table. So in the end, I will have tables, which clearly show which polygon and which track was produced to create it. (Just like `resdf`: there, each key showed which track and which polygon was used to create a particular entry.)

**How can I do this in BigQuery?**

The more "vectorized" the solution is, ie the less for loop or similar it has, the better for me, as my real world database is huge.

Comment: If I missed out something for reproducibility, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an advice on modeling this data in BigQuery

1. it is wasteful to model each track as a separate table. I would go with a single table for all tracks, and just add a column with track_id.
2. SQL tables are unordered - the rows don't maintain any order, unless you add it in a query with `ORDER BY` or similar operator. So if you model the points in the track as rows, and you do care about the order of the points: add another column, point_id. Thus the tracks table will have schema:

```
track_id INT64
point_id INT64
coord GEOGRAPHY
```

3. Another way to model such tracks is via arrays. In this case, a single row maps to the whole track, where one column is an array with track points. In this case the order of points within array (but not tracks rows within table) is guaranteed to be preserved. But you might run into scalability and performance issues with very long tracks, so I'd go with flat schema above, but for completeness this option would  have schema

```
track_id INT64
coords ARRAY<GEOGRAPHY>
```

Now let's generate some sample data similar to what you do:

```sql
create or replace table tmp.ps as 
select * from (
    select 
        1 poly_id, 
        st_geogfromtext('POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 1, 0 1, 0 0))') p
    union all
    select 
        2 poly_id, 
        st_geogfromtext('POLYGON((1 -1, 1.5 -1, 6.5 1, 5 1, 1 -1))') p
);

create or replace table tmp.tracks as 
select * from (
    select 1 track_id, 
        x point_id,
        ST_GeogPoint(x*0.3, x*0.1 - 0.1) g
    from unnest(generate_array(1, 30)) x
    union all 
    select 2 track_id, 
        x point_id,
        ST_GeogPoint(x*0.4, sin(x*0.4) - 0.8) g
    from unnest(generate_array(1, 50)) x
);
```

Here they are in [GeoViz](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/), using query

```sql
select * from
(select p from tmp.ps
union all
select g from tmp.tracks)
```

[image]

We can now join the two tables:

```sql
select poly_id, track_id, g
from tmp.ps
join tmp.tracks
on st_intersects(p, g)
order by poly_id, track_id
```

which gives you all the track points within polygons, polygon id and track id:

```
poly_id track_id    g
1       1       POINT(1.2 0.3)
1       1       POINT(1.5 0.4)
1       1       POINT(0.3 0)
1       1       POINT(0.6 0.1)
1       1       POINT(1.8 0.5)
1       1       POINT(0.9 0.2)
1       2       POINT(2 0.109297426825682)
1       2       POINT(1.2 0.132039085967226)
1       2       POINT(1.6 0.199573603041505)
2       2       POINT(2.8 -0.465011849844095)
```